# C++ Object-oriented programming

Tags: c++, object, program-entry-point

I have 1 question because I am pretty curious how to handle with such problem.
I have base class called "Pracownik" (Worker) and 2 subclasses which are made from public Pracownik;
- Informatyk (Informatic)
- Księgowy (Accountant)
Writing classes is easy. Made them pretty fast but I have small problem with main because I am helping friend with program but I was not using C++ for a while. So:

This is my header file "funkcje.h"

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Pracownik
{
 private:
  string nazwisko;
  int pensja;
 public:
  Pracownik(string="",int=0);
  ~Pracownik();
  string getNazwisko();
  int getPensja();
  friend double srednia_pensja(int,Pracownik);
};

class Informatyk : public Pracownik
{
 private:
  string certyfikat_Cisco;
  string certyfikat_Microsoft;
 public:
  Informatyk(string="",int=0, string="", string="");
  ~Informatyk();
  void info();
};

class Ksiegowy : public Pracownik
{
 private:
  bool audytor;
 public:
  Ksiegowy(string="",int=0, bool=false);
 ~Ksiegowy();
 void info();

};

double srednia_pensja(int,Pracownik);
```

These are definitions of my functions "funkcje.cpp"

```
#include "funkcje.h"

Pracownik::Pracownik(string a,int b)
{
  nazwisko=a;
  pensja=b;
}

Pracownik::~Pracownik()
{
}

string Pracownik::getNazwisko()
{
  return nazwisko;
}

int Pracownik::getPensja()
{
  return pensja;
}



Informatyk::Informatyk(string a, int b, string c, string d) : Pracownik(a,b)
{
  certyfikat_Cisco=c;
  certyfikat_Microsoft=d;
}

Informatyk::~Informatyk()
{
}



Ksiegowy::Ksiegowy(string a, int b, bool c) : Pracownik(a,b)
{
  audytor=c;
}

Ksiegowy::~Ksiegowy()
{
}

void Informatyk::info()
{
  cout<<"Nazwisko pracownika: "<<Pracownik::getNazwisko()<<endl;
  cout<<"Pensja pracownika: "<<Pracownik::getPensja()<<endl;
  cout<<"Certyfikat Cisco: "<<certyfikat_Cisco<<endl;
  cout<<"Certyfikat Microsoft: "<<certyfikat_Microsoft<<endl;
}


void Ksiegowy::info()
{
  cout<<"Nazwisko pracownika: "<<Pracownik::getNazwisko()<<endl;
  cout<<"Pensja pracownika: "<<Pracownik::getPensja()<<endl;
  cout<<"Audytor: ";
  if(audytor)
    cout<<"Tak"<<endl;
  else
    cout<<"Nie"<<endl;
}



double srednia_pensja(int a,Pracownik *b)
{

  return 0;
}
```

And finally main!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "funkcje.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Pracownik lista[10];
  Pracownik *lista_wsk = new Pracownik[10];
  Informatyk a("Kowalski1",1000,"Cisco1","Microsoft1");
  Informatyk b("Kowalski2",2000,"Cisco2","Microsoft2");
  Informatyk c("Kowalski3",3000,"Cisco3","Microsoft3");
  Ksiegowy d("Kowalski4",4000,1);
  Ksiegowy e("Kowalski5",5000,0);

  lista[0]=a;
  lista[1]=b;
  lista[2]=c;
  lista[3]=d;
  lista[4]=e;

  Informatyk *ab = new Informatyk("Kowalski1",1000,"Cisco1","Microsoft1");
  Informatyk *ac = new Informatyk("Kowalski2",2000,"Cisco2","Microsoft2");
  Informatyk *ad = new Informatyk("Kowalski3",3000,"Cisco3","Microsoft3");
  Ksiegowy *ae = new Ksiegowy("Kowalski4",3000,1);
  Ksiegowy *af = new Ksiegowy("Kowalski5",3000,0);

  lista_wsk[0]=*ab;
  lista_wsk[1]=*ac;
  lista_wsk[2]=*ad;
  lista_wsk[3]=*ae;
  lista_wsk[4]=*af;

  for(int i;i<5;i++)
    {

      lista[i].info();
      cout<<endl;
    }
  cout<<endl;

  //  for(int i;i<5;i++)
  // {

      //        lista_wsk[i].info();
  //  }



  return 0;
}
```

Ok and here goes my questions:
I had to create array which is filled with base class objects "Pracownik".
Secondary i had to create array which is full of pointers to class "Pracownik" objects.
(Hope those 2 first steps are done correctly)
Next thing I had to write to array 3 objects of class Informatic and 2 of class Accountant.
So I ve created 5 objects manually and added them into the array in such way array[0]=a;. I guess this is still good.
Next thing i had to create and add similar objects to array of pointers using new. So I ve created array with new and pointers to objects with new. (Hope thats correct 2).
And FINALLY:
I had to use info() on added to array objects.
This is my main question if my array is type "Pracownik" and I want to use function info() from subclasses how should I do that? And how compiler will know if he should use info() from Accountant or Informatic while I am trying to show those information using "for".

Comment: Provide `virtual void info() = 0;` in class `Pracownik`.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could translate the identifiers in your code into English.  You did provide some translations in your question but your code is still unnecessarily difficult to read and comprehend for people who only speak English.

Comment: 5gon12eder Sorry for that! Hoped that all information that I have translated are enough to understand the code. But anyway thanks for help I ve got the answer forgot about this object slicing and about existence of virtual functions. Gotta write some programs ;P becasue I start to forget the language.

Comment: A word to the wise for the betterment of mankind: write code in English please. Makes everything soooooo much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Oswald](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27469045/1392132) says in his answer,

```
Pracownik * lista_wsk = new Pracownik[10];
```

allocates an array of 10 `Pracownik` objects.  This is probably not what you want.  With polymorphism involved, we usually want to deal with *pointers* or references.  Hence, you'd want an array of `Pracownik *` pointers.  Since you already know at compile-time that it will have 10 members, there is no need for a dynamic allocation here.  I think you've meant to write

```
Pracownik * lista_wsk[10];
```

instead.  Now we don't put objects but pointers to objects into the array.  For example:

```
lista_wsk[2] = new Informatyk("Kowalski3", 3000, "Cisco3", "Microsoft3");
```

And then we can iterate over the items like so:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  std::cout << lista_wsk[i]->getNazwisko() << std::endl;
```

As you have already discovered, it is impossible to call a subclass function member on a superclass object.  It would be possible to figure out the actual type at run-time yourslf by means of a *cast*.

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  if (Informatyk * info_ptr = dynamic_cast<Informatyk *>(lista_wsk[i]))
    info_ptr->info();
```

`dynamic_cast` returns a pointer to the target class if this is possible or a `nullptr` (which evaluates to `false`, hence the conditional) otherwise.  Note however that this is considered very poor style.  It is better to use *virtual functions*.  Therefore, add

```
virtual void
info()
{
  // Do what is appropriate to do for a plain Pracownik.
  // Maybe leave this function empty.
}
```

to the superclass and *again* to the subclass

```
virtual void
info()  // override
{
  // Do what is appropriate to do for an Informatyk.
}
```

The function in the subclass with the same signature is said to *override* the function inherited from the superclass.  Since the function is marked as `virtual`, the compiler will generate additional code to figure out at run-time what version of the function to call.

If you are coding C++11, you can make the override explicit by placing the keyword `override` after its type as shown above (uncomment the `override`).  I recommend you use this to avoid bugs that arise from accidental misspelling or other typos.

Answer (score 2):

In an array of `Pracownik`, the elements are of type `Pracownik`. Any information about the objects being of a subclass of `Pracownik` are lost when you copy the elements into the array.

This is called *object slicing* and leads to the fact that there is no way to invoke `Informatyk::info()` on these objects.

If you want to call methods of a subclass, you have to prevent object slicing by storing pointers or references in the array.